# Как использовать файлы с весами обученной нейронной сети?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

В результате обучения нейронной сети для языкового перевода текстов основанной на tensorflow версии 2.12 и с архитектурой encoder decoder, были сохранены файлы с весами - checkpoint.
Вот пример кода:

```
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder)
checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)
```

Как построить модели нейронной сети, которая сможет использовать данные файлы с весами для предсказаний?

Comment: Инициализируете модель точно такой же архитектуры - и загружаете в неё веса. В официальной документации всё написано: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load?hl=ru

Comment: Спасибо, официальная документация не особо помогает.

Comment: Да, непонятно, где же у вас модель то в случае, если вы единую модель не создаёте, а делаете сразу чекпоинт от нескольких моделей. А файлы какие создаются при создании чекпоинта? Может там отдельные файлы для каждой модели?

Comment: Модель архитектуры encoder decoder. Файлы создаются следующие:  checkpoint, ckpt-1.index, ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680088/saving-tensorflow-encoder-decoder-and-attention) на английском СО используют такую команду для загрузки данных из сохранённого чекпоинта, конфигурация которого очень похожа на вашу. Я так понимаю, из списка чекпоинтов (если их несколько в каталоге) тут берётся самый последний. `encoder` и `decoder` в данном случае - модели, сконфигурированные таким же образом как модель, от которой записаны веса, но не тренированные, с пустыми весами.

```py
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder)
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

Comment: Я забыл указать эту строку в вопросе. И теперь понимаю, что вопрос был задан не совсем корректно. Но тем не менее считаю, что данный ответ нужно отметить как правильный. ..хотя и не совсем понятный в плане применения.

Comment: @GaloGramma Теперь уже мне непонятно - а что же вы хотите? Сохранённые веса может использовать только **в точности такая же модель**, как та, из которой эти веса были сохранены. Т.е. создаёте пустую модель той же конфигурации, как та, от которой сохранили веса. Грузите веса. Используете модель. Т.е. вместо тренировки модели загружаются готовые веса. Или вы что-то другое хотели? Если вы хотели в какую-то другую модель эти веса загрузить, то это задача может и возможная, но очень не тривиальная.

Comment: Задача использовать обученную модель на её же весах. На локальном сервере модель обучается и корректно работает. Но, при выгрузке этой модели на веб сервер, модель не выходит из цикла обучения. То есть модель обучается не переставая. Я думаю, что нужно мне создать новый вопрос, и предоставить в нем весь код.

Comment: @GaloGramma Если проблемы с обучением, то непонятно, при чём тут загрузка из чекпоинта )  Да, лучше задать ещё один вопрос, однозначно

Comment: Проблема не с обучением, модель успешно обучается, а именно в использовании обученной модели не её же весах.

Comment: "Но, при выгрузке этой модели на веб сервер, модель не выходит из цикла обучения." - это что тогда значит? Какое обучение, если модель уже обучена? Да, и версии библиотек у вас одинаковые и там и там? По ссылке той писали, что могут быть проблемы, если сохранить веса в одной версии TF, а читать в другой.

Comment: И keras и tf версии 2.12.0. Keras устанавливается вместе с tf. Модель не выходит из циклы обучения означает, что через каждые 2 эпохи модель обучается и перезаписывает новые веса в ту же директорию.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю. Зачем вы обучаете модель, если она уже обучена и вы её используете с готовыми весами? Я думаю надо задавать новый вопрос и приводить код, по-другому никак.

Comment: Не получается использовать. Новый вопрос почти готов.